# Adding UIBezierPath to UIImage without using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a UIImage in memory (not on the screen) in which I want to apply a UIBezierPath drawing to. Is this possible?

All the methods I have seen involve using the screen (UIGraphicsBeginImageContext method)

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`? You don't have to draw it to screen

Comment: what? I thought UIGraphicsBeginImageContext took a photo of the screen?

Comment: No, it creates a context for you to draw on. After drawing to the context you can call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` to get the image (in memory) to do whatever you want with - submit to server, present in an `UIImageView` .. etc

Comment: I want to erase part of the image based on a UIBezierPath - do you know how to do this?

Comment: create a mask with the bezier path and use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule on the target layer to remove the area of the mask - read the CALayer documentation

Comment: is there a way to do it blending the path as transparent with the path i want to erase?